Formula Syntax Error (Account to Quote)
We are trying to create a basic formula field to pull an account field into the quote object (see below)
Account.Customer_Registration_No__c

However the syntax errors out advising "Field Account does not exist. Check spelling."
The Account is an Object, not a field - we want to pull the field from the Account Object to the Quote object.
We have done similar in the same formula format from contact to quote and it checks out fine.

Based on this answer, looks like you might have to pull your Customer_Registration_No__c from the Opportunity object like Opportunity.Account.Customer_Registration_No__c

Ever since Quote has existed as a standard object, the Account relationship has never worked in formulas. Opportunity.Account does work, however.
